# Loading entries from MySQL into Java table based on search field

Tags: java, mysql, search

I have a MySQL table with entries already in it and I have it connected to my Java program so it displays the table values whenever the program is run. I'm basically trying to implement a search field where the user can type any attribute's value and all the entries that match that value will be loaded into the table. Then the user will be able to select the right entry that matches and they can edit, or update that entry's information. This would be useful for me particularly when you have entries that have the same value, for instance first name, last name, or zip code.

```
try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM donors WHERE donor_id = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, txtSearch1.getText());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        tblDonors.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } 

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM donors WHERE first_name = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, txtSearch1.getText());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        tblDonors.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

The search field only searches for the second query, but not the first, so I can type a name and the matching names will load into the table, but when I try to input an id number, nothing happens. I'm fairly new to this, but I think it has something to do with my resultset object? Not exactly sure though. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the second result overwrites the first.  I think the easiest solution is to use `or` in the where clause, like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM donors WHERE (donor_id = ?) or (first_name = ?)";
ps.setString(1, txtSearch1.getText());
// but of course there are 2 ?'s now, we have to give the value to the second one
// as well
ps.setString(2, txtSearch1.getText());
```

Due to the way placeholders work in JDBC you'll have to provide a value for each `?`.